I want to fetch a data from another python file everytime i execute the other one
I know that whenever i use from my_file_contains_data.py import data_i_want
i can access the data i want and i can use it for 'if' statements.
but in 'my_file_contains_data.py' file, the 'data_i_want' is a variable that can changes.
and when the 'data_i_want' changes, it does not change in the main file i work, it always stays the same value in the beginning.
Here are my codes:
main file:
 from cmds.channelproctection import curstat
 @bot.event
 async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
      if channel.guild.id == my_guild_id and curstat==1:
           memberRole = channel.guild.get_role(693197190377766931) # Server's Default Member Role ID.
           async for entry in channel.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete):
                if not entry.user.id == 472911936951156740:
                     try:
                          await entry.user.edit(nick='some swear words', roles=[memberRole], reason='Deleting a Channel.')
                          await channel.clone(reason=f'Channel re-opened because {entry.user.name} deleted the channel.')
                          chan2=bot.get_channel(my_announcement_channel)
                          await chan2.send(f"@everyone, {entry.user.mention}, deleted **{channel.name}** channel. some swears")                 
                     except Forbidden:
                          ownerid = bot.get_user(owners[0])
                          chan = await ownerid.create_dm()
                          chan3 = await bot.get_user(my_friends_id).create_dm()
                          await channel.clone(reason=f"@everyone, {entry.user.mention}, deleted **{channel.name}** channel. some swears")
                          await chan.send(f"{entry.user.name}, removed {channel.name}.")
                          await chan3.send(f"{entry.user.name}, removed {channel.name} ")
      elif channel.guild.id == my_guild_id and curstat==0:
           async for entry in channel.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete):
                if not entry.user.id == 472911936951156740: # VoiceMaster ID
                     ownerid = bot.get_user(owners[0])
                     chan = await ownerid.create_dm()
                     await chan.send(f"Channel protection is off but {entry.user.name}, removed {channel.name}!")
      elif channel.guild.id == IEEM and curstat not in [0, 1]:
           print('there is a huge problem!')
           await bot.close()


channel-protection (a.k.a 'my_file_contains_data'):
curstat=1

@commands.command(aliases = ["chanprot", 'chapro',"sex"],hidden=True)
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def channelprotection(ctx, state : str):
     global curstat
     if state in ["open", "turnon", "on", '1']:
          if not curstat==1:
               curstat = 1
               await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
               await ctx.send("Channel protection is on!",reference=ctx.message, mention_author=False)
          else:
               await ctx.message.add_reaction("")
               await ctx.send("Already On.")
     elif state in ['close', 'turnoff', 'off', '0']:
          if not curstat==0:
               curstat = 0
               await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
               await ctx.send("Caution, Channel protection is disabled!",reference=ctx.message, mention_author=False)
          else:
               await ctx.message.add_reaction("")
               await ctx.send("Already Off.")
     else:
          await ctx.send("Use open for turning on, use close for turning of.")

async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(channelprotection)

When i used turn off command, it gives me a reply but 'curstat' variable doesn't changes so bot still recreates channels when i or someone trys to remove a channel. i tried adding the line from cmds.channelproctection import curstat after event handlers and define function
like this:
@bot.event
     async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
          from cmds.channelprotection import curstat
          if channel.guild.id == 693193721612861511 and curstat==1:
...

it worked but i dont think this usage is correct. is this true, did i solve my problem or is there a good and logical way to 'fix' this issue?

You can either use global variables or save the content of the variable in a file/database. This would be the best approch; by using a global variable, on the bot restart you will lose the previous state of the variable.
To save a variable to a file, I reccomend you checking Pickle. If you want to start looking into a DB, SQLite is probably the best start.

for ans1:
yeah, i tried assigning curstat as a global variable but as you can see. when i imported on startup, it just read the first time. not when it changed. i tried importing everytime "on event" called but it just doesnt fit in my mind using this.
for ans2:
i think i'll do this. at first, i thought could i assign it using write function to a text file but it just seems also not very effective. i will try pickle and give you feedback. thanks for suggestion. but i really dont wanna use db, so i just stick with pickle or writing it to a text file or sum.
